# Rails error when using %d (deprecated) on translating dates, what should i use instead?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, internationalization

In language file `es.yml` i have

```
time:
    formats:
      short: "%d %b %H:%M"
```

when i try using it like:

```
<%= l my_object.created_at, :format => :short %>
```

it shows the following error

```
ActionView::TemplateError (missing interpolation argument in "%{count} %b %H:%M" ({:object=>Fri, 11 Jun 2010 09:00:00 CDT -05:00} given)) on line #68 of app/views/matches/_by_session.html.erb:  
65:               `</div>`  
66:   
67:               `<div>`  
68:                       `<%= l match.starts_at, :format => :short %>`  
69:               `</div>`  
70:  
71:             `</div>`
```

How should I display the day... if `%d` doesnt work anymore.... Any ideas???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this problem and it took me ages to work it out.

For me the problem was I also had Rails version 3 beta installed and a prerequisite for that is the I18n gem.

This is not required for version 2.* of rails and simply uninstalling this gem (I18n) resolved my issues.

Answer (score 0):

Yep indeed i had the same kind of error:

```
I18n::MissingInterpolationArgument in Admin/campaigns#index
Showing app/views/admin/campaigns/_campaign.html.erb where line #3 raised:
missing interpolation argument in "%Y/%m/%{count}" ({:object=>Mon, 19 Jul 2010 15:15:57 CEST +02:00} given)
```

Uninstalling the i18n gem fixed it